# Multiple UICollectionViewCells to segue to separate UIViewController

Tags: uicollectionview, uistoryboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue, uicollectionviewcell

I have two separate UICollectionViewCells with identifiers MY_CELL and MY_CELL_2

I then wrote this:

```
#import "MyCollectionView"
#import "Cell.h"
#import "VC1.h"
#import "VC2.h"

    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

            Cell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MY_CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];



        Cell *cell2 = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MY_CELL_2" forIndexPath:indexPath];



    }
```

I then have two UIVCs, UIVC1 and UIVC2 I want MY_CELL to segue to UIVC1 and MY_CELL_2 to segue to UIVC2 so I wrote:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"cell_to_vc1"])
    {

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell *)sender;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];

    UIVC1 *vc1 = (VC1 *)segue.destinationViewController;


    }

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"cell2_to_vc2"])
    {

      UICollectionViewCell *cell2 = (UICollectionViewCell *)sender;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];

    UIVC2 *vc2 = (VC2 *)segue.destinationViewController;

    }


}
```

However, I can't even see the second cell being displayed. Only MY_CELL is visible.

Anyone know what I'm doing incorrectly and why I cannot see the second cell?

Comment: Tell me what is requirement?

Comment: @SamkitJain The requirement is that I can have multiple UICollectionViewCells and each cell and segue into a different UIViewController. So, cell1 segues into UIViewController1 and cell2 segues into UIViewController2 when clicked

Answer (score 0):

You must have a single identifier for cell. In didselect method, you have to check which cell is clicked and and inprpare segue just check the segue identifier you have mapped to and perform segue.